# Laravel 5.8 Won’t Connect to Non-Local Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am having an issue where a new Laravel Project (5.8) will not connect to a non-local database. I continue getting an “Access Denied for User...” error. I know that the configuration is correct because I have another project running in 5.6 connecting to the same database with the same configuration and it works. It appears that once I use a hostname other than “localhost”, it breaks. It was working locally until I attempted to connect to another non-local database.

I believe Laravel is not accepting the hostname correctly. I have recached everything as well, with no luck. The access denied error always shows the same local hostname of the machine the project is on, never the remote hostname in the env, so I assume it is trying to connect to that. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I am stumped with no idea where to go.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I know for sure there is not a configuration error, IP access error, or caching error as I have already troubleshooted all of these possible issues (it sounds like one of these issues). My env and the error are below (anything starting with "my" is the correct information that I have changed for security):

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql.myURL.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDbName
DB_USERNAME=myDbUsername
DB_PASSWORD=myDbPassword
```

```sql
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myDbUsername'@'NOTmysql.myURL.com' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `myTable`)
```

NOTmysql.myURL.com in the error actually happens to be the local hostname of the server that the website is running on, but myDbUsername is the username I set in the configuration.

Comment: Please make sure you are using correct db config in .env file & config/database is defult set to use mysql... also validate the .env conifiguration is getting used in that config/database.php file..

Comment: Also are you trying to use docker here?

Comment: Yes the env is being used in the database config file. I am using MySQL as configured. Again, my configuration is the same as another site that is working without issue so I know it is not a configuration issue.

Comment: And no docker here.

Comment: Check your database users. The username with the host has to exist exactly as you call it. If you want to connect as someuser@blah then that user has to exist exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

Embarrassing mistake on my part, but I figured out the answer to my question. I have a # in the password and it was causing the part of the password after the # to be read as a comment so it was only using part of the password. I put the password in quotes and everything is now working.

Answer (score 1):

@IanCowan do try to connect with simple php connect script. Verify does this working for you on the same repository... just placed that php file in /public folder.

And open/browse url to that file. Don't forgot to change the config.

This is just to ensure... there is no issue at connection end.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Ian awesome... now please do confirm the configuration settings... change .env DB_HOST="mysql.myURL.com"

Comment: If still not connencted... do share the config/database.php and .env settings.

Comment: @Ian are you able to connect?

Comment: I am not (and my apologies I've been out and about). Here are the .env and config/database.php files: https://gist.github.com/iccowan/4621eca2ad14cd4059052b8ed6fd72e8

Comment: Try setting `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/forge?charset=UTF-8` in .env file

Comment: Replace values with actual one

Comment: driver://username:password@host:port/database?options

Comment: Figured it out... see my answer for the fix. Can't believe it took me this long to find the mistake, lol.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Go to the .env file and check the database configuration

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravelDb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null
```

**2.** Then restart the apache server and refresh the page

**3.** Exit/close and re-run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

**4.** Clear the old configuration cache and config file

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Now your error should be gone.

Comment: I have already followed these steps with no luck. The hostname still is not updating. I can try again, but I don’t think it is going to work (I’ve already done it about 10 times). I know it’s not an IP access error, config caching error, or configuration error (as I’ve already troubleshooted all of these).

Comment: Update: retried the steps as you suggested and, as expected, no luck.